# Bug with Tikz arrows.meta?

Tags: errors, tikz-arrows

I am using the new Tikz `arrows.meta` library.  Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0, 0) edge [Latex-] (1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives

```
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible with a current up-to-date TeX distribution.